# how to read a pdf file with using java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to read a pdf file and display it in the UI in non editable ,copy protected read only format.

1)Need to read a  PDF file which might contain Images

(I tried using iText jar but that does not read images)

2)Display it in UI as read only.

Kindly help me by giving  inputs for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on pdfbox.apache.org and  textpdf.com/

Both are open source, free libraries. 
For more information try some googling.
There are a lot of commercial libraries as well.

Comment: any idea on how to display without storing the file in db? Since its going to be a fixed pdf file which the user should be able to see

Comment: Why storing file in DB? All APIs use stream abstraction, so you can display data from any source.

Comment: I got the content printed in the console ,I require to show it in the jsp file.So only I asked that question.Pls be explicit in the answer so as to help me. I am a beginner .

Answer (score 1):

You have lot of options available; some are

1. [iText](http://itextpdf.com/)
2. [Asprise](http://asprise.com/product/javapdf/)
3. [All other options](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries)